# How can I show 'download in progess' in progress bars of multiple videos in RecyclerView when I return from another activity?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a ListView which contains a video list and on click download video button which shows the download progress in a circular progress bar. If I click on a number video for download, then it will start to show progress. But when I click on another activity and come back to the same activity, the remaining progress is not shown in the progress bar and it does not appear.

What should I do to see the remaining video progress in the ListView which I clicked previously? I used a download manager to download a video and show progress in the progress bar.

I want the same functionality which is used in WhatsApp; if you click on a video, it shows the download progress and also after you revisit the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to save downloadId in local database.
`DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(strUrl));
                                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                                    request.setTitle(strDownloadFileName);
                                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, strDownloadFileName);
                                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                                    long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

```
                                databaseHelper.insertProgress(positionItem,downloadId);'
```

create the  function for get progress against downloadId 
` private int getProgressFromDownloadID(long donloadId){

```
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
    q.setFilterById(donloadId);

    Cursor  cursor = manager.query(q);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
    int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {

    }

    int dl_progress = (int) ((double)bytes_downloaded / (double)bytes_total * 100f);

    return dl_progress;
}`
```